# ajax form submiting is not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to load the php code without refreshing the page but some how my Ajax cod is not working.what part is wrong ?
I wouldn't use jquery or other frameworks by the way.
Is the problem with my javascript code ?
Shoud I use jquery for this or it can be done without it ?
What is the advantages of using jquery ?
thank you.

html and javascript :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit your info</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submited()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
         document.getElementById("stext").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","submit.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" onsubmit="submited()">
<fieldset>
<legend style="color:red">Complete the fields:</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="f_fname"></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="f_lname"></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mail:</td><td><input type="email" name="f_mail"></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Your Resume:</td><td><textarea name="f_detail"></textarea></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Experience:</td><td>less than 1 year:<input type="radio" name="f_year" value="one"/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>1-3 years:<input type="radio" name="f_year" value="onetothree"/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>more than 3 years:<input type="radio" name="f_year" value="three"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="stext"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

php :

```
<?php
require("pdate.php");
$fname=$_POST['f_fname'];
$lname=$_POST['f_lname'];
$mail=$_POST['f_mail'];
$detail=$_POST['f_detail'];
$year=$_POST['f_year'];
$date=pdate("y-m-d h:i:s");
$fp=fopen("database.txt","a");
fwrite($fp,"Name=$fname\n\rLastName=$lname\n\rMail=$mail\n\rDetail=$detail\n\rYear=$year\n\rDate=$date\n\r--------------------\n\r");
echo "Your Data has been submited.";
```

Comment: I recommend using jQuery, because like the description of it says: "It makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler with an easy-to-use API that works across a multitude of browsers" Give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `return false` in the `submited()` function to stop submitting the form. Also using jquery is much more simple.

Also you do not send the data to your script, which you should do by using e.g.

```
xmlhttp.send("f_fname="+f_fname+"&f_lname="+f_lname);
```

instead of

```
xmlhttp.send();
```

But remember to assign the values to variables. You can do it by giving the inputs the ID and assign the variable in js. So with that 2 edited (you should add the rest by yourself) in your script it would be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit your info</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submited()
 {
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
     xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else
 {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
         document.getElementById("stext").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
 }
 var f_fname = document.getElementById('f_fname').value;
 var f_lname = document.getElementById('f_lname').value;
 xmlhttp.open("POST","submit.php",true);
 xmlhttp.send("f_fname="+f_fname+"&f_lname="+f_lname); 
 return false;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" onsubmit="submited()">
<fieldset>
<legend style="color:red">Complete the fields:</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="f_fname" name="f_fname"></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" id="f_fname" name="f_lname"></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Mail:</td><td><input type="email" name="f_mail"></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Your Resume:</td><td><textarea name="f_detail"></textarea></br></td></tr>
<tr><td>Experience:</td><td>less than 1 year:<input type="radio" name="f_year" value="one"/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>1-3 years:<input type="radio" name="f_year" value="onetothree"/></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>more than 3 years:<input type="radio" name="f_year" value="three"/></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="stext"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Add `return false;`

```
function submited()
{
  ..
  return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return submited()">
```

Comment: The refreshing page problem is solved but the form's data is not submiting anymore in the database.txt file .

Comment: Then look for my answer.